# jQuery keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I would like to capture a keyboard event that is:

- *before* the user lifts their finger from the key
- *after* the characters from the keyboard event have registered in the input box.

To clarify, view this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HpXuU/4/). When `keypress` fires, the `input` value has not been updated yet.

[Edit]

Apparently I wasn't clear as to what I need.

The function must be called **before** the user lifts their finger up from the key, but **after** the key's character is placed in the input box. So the following do not work:

- keydown:  at the `keypress` event, the value in the text box has not been updated
- keypress: at the `keypress` event, the value in the text box has not been updated
- keyup:    this is called when the user lifts their finger, which is too late.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `input` event, which works in recent versions of all major browsers:

```
var input = document.getElementById("your_input_id");
input.oninput = function() {
    alert(input.value);
};
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE <= 8. However, in those browsers you can use the `propertychange` event on the `value` property instead:

```
input.onpropertychange = function() {
    if (window.event.propertyName == "value") {
        alert(input.value);
    }
};
```

SO regular JavaScript answerer [@Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) has covered this in detail on his blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20140626060232/http://whattheheadsaid.com/2011/10/update-html5-oninput-event-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: Amazing, I have never seen this event before, but it works perfectly!

Comment: @franzlorenzon: Yeah, Andy's blog seems to be broken. I'll message him.

Comment: What if change in input is done programmatically? Is there a way to catch this change? (example: input is read only, changed only through some javascript code - how to catch this change?)

Comment: Please update or remove that blog link, its redirecting to spammer website.

Comment: @Maidul: That's a shame. There were a couple of useful things on that site. I'll remove or replace the link.

Answer (score 3):

You could listen on `keydown` event and store the value in a variable. That variable would have the value as it was before the new input, and the new input would be included in the `keyup` event

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I misunderstood your requirements, but there isn't an event that would meet your needs. The only thing I can think of to simulate this behaviour is the following:

- listen on `keydown/keypress`
- get the value from the `event` object (get `event.which`, then convert it to actual value)
- use a variable like I mentioned in the original advice and concatenate the new input to it

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpXuU/13/

This is obviously not a perfect solution, as it needs some (one might argue unnecessary) work to get done right. I would advise to rethink your needs, but if this behavior is absolutely what you need, I think this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: I need the new input value *before* the key is lifted.

Comment: So you need the code to be psychic and know the user is going to lift their finger the next millisecond and not the one after?

Comment: @SW Well, umm... isn't that exactly what my suggestion would do? Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HpXuU/10/

Comment: keydown will give you the value before the key is lifted

Comment: The fiddle does not work if the user is not typing at the end of the text box.

Answer (score 3):

Use [keyup event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUMtj/)

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

It happens *after* you lift the key. I don't know what you want to achieve, but you can store the state before lifting the key (on `keydown` or `keypress`) and restoring later if needed. You also can [stop the output in the `keyup` event using `e.preventDefault()`](http://jsfiddle.net/rUMtj/1/), so even after the key is up it will not register the values in the area.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // read that.value
    }, 0);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HpXuU/8/

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the timeout is not guaranteed to be called right at it's appointed time.

Comment: @SW The `setTimeout` mechanism indeed has a minimum delay which is cca. 10ms (depending on the browser). However, you can define a `setZeroTimeout` function ([code is here](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts)) which will execute immediately after the keypress event handler returns.