# :not(:empty) CSS selector is not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having a heck of a time with this particular CSS selector which does not want to work when I add `:not(:empty)` to it. It seems to work fine with any combination of the other selectors:

```css
input:not(:empty):not(:focus):invalid { border-color: #A22; box-shadow: none }
```

If I remove the `:not(:empty)` part, it works just fine. Even if I change the selector to `input:not(:empty)` it still won't select input fields which have text typed into them. Is this broken or am I just not allowed to use `:empty` within a `:not()` selector?

The only other thing I can think of is that browsers are still saying that the element is empty because it has no children, just a "value" per say. Does the `:empty` selector not have separate functionality for an input element versus a regular element? This doesn't seem probable though because using `:empty` on a field and typing something into it will cause the alternate effects to go away (because it is no longer empty).

Tested in Firefox 8 and Chrome.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Can I quote you part of the [API reference for the `:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/): "Some other elements, on the other hand, are empty (i.e. have no children) by definition: `<input>`, `<img>`, `<br>`, and `<hr>`, for example."

Comment: @Virendra: That is the relevant code, but I've added the actual CSS rules to it. If I remove the `:not(:empty)`, the red border works as expected for an input that is not in focus but is invalid.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Being a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), an `<input>` element is considered [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1) by the HTML definition of "empty", since the content model of all void elements *is always empty*. So they will always match the `:empty` pseudo-class, whether or not they have a value. This is also why their value is represented by an attribute in the start tag, rather than text content within start and end tags.

Also, from the [Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo):

> The `:empty` pseudo-class represents an element that has no children at all. In terms of the document tree, only element nodes and content nodes (such as DOM text nodes, CDATA nodes, and entity references) whose data has a non-zero length must be considered as affecting emptiness;

Consequently, `input:not(:empty)` will never match anything in a proper HTML document. (It would still work in a hypothetical XML document that defines an `<input>` element that can accept text or child elements.)

I don't think you can style empty `<input>` fields dynamically using just CSS (i.e. rules that apply whenever a field is empty, and don't once text is entered). You can select *initially* empty fields if they have an empty `value` attribute (`input[value=""]`) or lack the attribute altogether (`input:not([value])`), but that's about it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't remember what I did to get the effects to go away with just the `input:empty`. Perhaps I typed something wrong, who knows.

Comment: Re last paragraph in the answer, `input` elements can be styled dynamically (in sufficiently modern browsers) if you can use the `required` attribute in HTML markup. Then you can use `:valid` and `:invalid` in CSS to test for nonempty vs. empty value of the control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-with-css

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela unless you are also using pattern attribute.

Comment: input:not([value='']) will select an input with a value ;)

Comment: @Chris Love: Inputs with an *initial* (on page load) value.

Answer (score 74):

You could try using :placeholder-shown...

```css
input {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition: border-color 200ms;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.validation {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: crimson;
  transition: opacity;
}

input:required:valid {
  border-color: forestgreen;
}

input:required:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  border-color: crimson;
}

input:required:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .validation {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="e-mail" required>
<div class="validation">Not valid</span>
```

no great support though... [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown)

Comment: pretty good support though...[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown)

Comment: Good old Internet Explorer (Y)

Comment: @rorymorris89 even latest version of EDGE doesn't support :-(

Comment: @Mo it does today, I just found and used this solution :)

Comment: Works perfect and if don't want to use a placeholder in that particular form, placeholder=" " works just fine.

Answer (score 68):

It is possible with inline javascript `onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"` & `input:not([value=""]):not(:focus):invalid`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mhsyfvv9/

```css
input:not([value=""]):not(:focus):invalid {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" value="" placeholder="valid mail" onchange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" />
```

Comment: Isn't the `onchange` event better in this case? Since you can edit input values with `Right click > Cut` as well (for example). Tested it: works fine.

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me with input type email.

Comment: If you're using React you don't even need the JS part as you're already most probably doing `value={myInputValue}` (which sets the `value` attribute itself not just the property)

Answer (score 20):

```css
.floating-label-input {
  position: relative;
  height:60px;
}
.floating-label-input input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.floating-label-input label {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.floating-label-input input:focus ~ label, .floating-label-input input:focus ~ label, .floating-label-input input:valid ~ label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #33bb55;
}
.floating-label-input .line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  left: 0;
}
.floating-label-input .line:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  background: #33bb55;
  height: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.floating-label-input input:focus ~ .line:after, .floating-label-input input:focus ~ .line:after, .floating-label-input input:valid ~ .line:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-label-input">
      <input type="text" id="id" required/>
      <label for="id" >User ID</label>
      <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Love this as a nice, CSS-only interactive effect. Though would want to point out to folks that this is dependent on 1) having your fields be marked `required`, even if that's not what the form calls for, and 2) having no other requirements like `minlength` or `pattern`, as tabbing away with a partially-filled field will cause the `<label>` to cover up your text. But for quick UI demo, it's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 8):

You may approach this differently; omit the use of the `:empty` pseudo-class, and utilize `input` events to detect a significant value in the `<input>` field, then style it accordingly:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var bg = this.value ? 'green' : 'red';
    this.style.backgroundColor = bg;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
#inputList li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#inputList li input,
#inputList li label {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}
#inputList li input {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
#inputList li label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="inputList">
  <li>
    <label for="username">Enter User Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Related

- [Another post on DOM Mutation Events, suggesting the use of `input` Events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5614764/547020) (DOM Mutation Events are now deprecated in DOM level 4, and have been replaced by DOM Mutation Observers).

---

*<del>**Disclaimer:** note that `input` events [are currently experimental](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#event-input-input), and probably not widely supported.</del> nope! forget about it - it's a [living standard now](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#event-input-input).*

Answer (score 7):

Since placeholder disappear on input, you can use:

```
input:placeholder-shown{
    //rules for not empty input
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check whether the input field is empty or not you can try this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder='Placeholder'/>
```

**CSS**

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown){
   background-color: red;
}
```

Since Placeholder get vanishes when something is typed in the input field so we can check whether Placeholder is visible or not through **CSS**

Answer (score 3):

Another pure CSS solution

```css
.form{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.form input{
  margin-top:10px;
}
.form label{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label{
    top:-10px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="inputFName" placeholder="Firstname">
    <label class="label" for="inputFName">Firstname</label>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" id="inputLName" placeholder="Lastname">
    <label class="label" for="inputLName">Lastname</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do trick by adding `placeholder` to input with empty value then add `input:not(:placeholder-shown)`

```html
<input type="text" placeholder=" ">
```

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown){
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that placeholder doesn't have to be filled. So far, this seems to be the best solution I can find, as an empty placeholder is completely semantically valid. Using `required` attribute is only valid if your form calls for requiring all fields. Hopefully, the working groups will fix the shortcomings of `:empty` or create a separate, purely-CSS option for this very common use-case.

Answer (score 1):

pure css solution

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s;
    transition: opacity 0s;
    text-align: right;
}
/* Chrome <=56, Safari < 10 */
input:-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s;
    transition: opacity 0s;
    text-align: right;
}
/* FF 4-18 */
input::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s;
    transition: opacity 0s;
    text-align: right;
}
/* FF 19-51 */
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0s;
    transition: opacity 0s;
    text-align: right;
}
/* IE 10+ */
input::placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0s;
    text-align: right;
}
/* Modern Browsers */

*:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   opacity: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
/* Chrome <=56, Safari < 10 */
*:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
/* FF 4-18 */
*:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
/* FF 19-50 */
*:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
/* IE 10+ */
*:focus::placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
/* Modern Browsers */

input:focus {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
input:not([value=""])
```

This works because we are selecting the input only when there isn't an empty string.

Comment: works for me, thnx

Answer (score -2):

This should work in modern browsers:

```css
input[value]:not([value=""])
```

It selects all inputs with value attribute and then select inputs with non empty value among them.

Comment: This would not be dynamic, though. It would only select input elements which have the *attribute* defined as `value=""`. Typing/removing something in the box would not cause any changes.

Answer (score -3):

You can use &:valid on your input and that make the trick.