# Apply different styles to input text field when empty (using CSS)?

Tags: css

For instance, a freshly loaded form contains an `<input type="text">` which has a green background colour. Once the user enters a value into the field, I would like it to be coloured blue instead.

Is it possible to accomplish this purely using CSS? I understand there is the `input[type='text'][value]` selector. However, this does not reflect any changes to the form made by the user after it has finished loading, so if the form loaded with no value, it would remain unchanged regardless of what the user does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could give the textfield the `required` attribute:

```
<input type="text" required />
```

and then check for validity with CSS:

```
input:invalid { background: green; }
```

or the opposite (only different for old browsers):

```
input:valid { background: blue; }
```

Comment: If you're writing in XML syntax, you'll want to expand that attribute to `required="required"`...

Comment: why would I want to force the required attribute just for that? this is not a good solution

Comment: @vsync If the field isn't required, I agree. For purely styling, it's not a good solution. If the field is required, it is.

Comment: also the input's type has to be "text" or else probably this won't work as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this using JavaScript. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/eZ9vL/) that uses jQuery.

If you want to change the `background-color` on `focus` only, you can use the aptly named `:focus` pseudo-selector. [Here's an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/WMEWg/).

Comment: Ah well, I was hoping to keep appearance confined to stylesheets. Thanks for the script, and the js tool.

Comment: Sure. `:focus` is a decent pseudo-selector that will do much of what you want, but we're used to so much customization now that relies heavily on JS. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using CSS only.

```
  input:placeholder-shown{
    background:#cacaca;
  }
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58536710).