# SCSS check if a text field has user input

Tags: sass

I'm trying to have different styles for whether a user has typed something into a text field or not.  There doesn't seem to be a pseudo-class (like :hover or :focus) for this, but honestly, I'm not even sure how to google for it.  I was thinking I could use an @if but im also not sure how to go about that.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you using precompiled SASS (like with SimpLESS or Scout), or something like sass.js to compile / interpret the SASS on demand?

Comment: Sass knows nothing about the DOM or anything about your document, it only compiles to CSS.  CSS *does* have psuedo classes like `:required` or `:invalid`.

Comment: There's an answer in another question regarding this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8695114/1384441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Sass (as cimmanon said), it's only a superset for css; you can only create rules for some pseudo-classes / cases.

You can validate fields with JavaScript or server-side languages - there are tons of plugins for almost any JS frameworks, and for vanilla JS also.

Just one example: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine