# When input has text the go bottom should not hide

Tags: css

Follwoing is the snippet in which when user clicks on the textbox then its label goes to bottom. What I am trying to do is that the label doesnot go to bottom on click. It should go to bottom when there is a text and should not hide if there is tet in the input field.Kindly let me know how can I modify the following snippet so it works in this manner.Thanks,

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/CiflJ

Comment: [You can't detect with CSS only if an input has text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16957328/1654265)

Comment: The link you've given us is a working version? What have you tried?