# Style empty textbox - CSS only solution

Tags: html, css, is-empty

**Update - Mar-24-2016**

I wanted to generalize the concerns but looks like it has been comprehended to be specific, my bad. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191632/style-empty-textbox-css-only-solution/36208986#36208986) is is 100% solution to the example I used earlier.

[image]

Please refer this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sarbbottam/pen/JXNQmZ)

So the idea behind **Style empty textbox**, was

```
textbox:empty ~ label {
 // position it as floating label
}
```

**Looks like it is not possible in CSS right now, may be in future.**

### Thank you every one for your help.

**Update - Mar-23-2016**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191632/style-empty-textbox-css-only-solution#answer-36191834) is close.
**But using `:invalid` is not an option**, as it makes the field mandatory with `required=true` attribute.

---

[image: empty and non empty state's style]

Please refer this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sarbbottam/full/remvVv/) for the desired behavior, with javascript.The demo is for the sake of explaining, how it should behave, **using javascript is not the intended behavior**. Also the **color used is just for the sake of contrast, is has nothing to do with validation**

---

**Is there any way to style an empty textbox with CSS only?**

I tried [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) `pseudo-class`, unfortunately `textbox` is always detected as empty; as it has no children or text-node. To be precise, `textbox` is a self-closing tag.

> > The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are considered.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried playing with active and focus?

Comment: The **focus** attribute is close, but not exactly what you want ---> **http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus**

Comment: @Matthew I dont think, `active` and `focus` tells you if the the field is empty or not

Comment: I don't believe CSS has any way of telling whether or not an input box is empty, but you can get incredibly close with active and focus. Here's a similar question any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/en3Lxtsn/ is really the closest you're going to get with pure CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have a css only solution (as of now) for the updated post.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with the use of `:invalid` and setting the `input` to `required="true"`

```css
input { 
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:red; 
}
input:invalid {
  background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<input id="in1" required="true">
```

[MDN :invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Ainvalid)

Comment: I was thinking about :invalid, but then you're forced to use this input - it's not bad if this field must have a value, but what if it's actually not required? I guess it is the only way.

Comment: @Matthew I think the required attributes are enforced in javascript, so if he doesn't use the required semantics already, then he can just continue to ignore them.

Comment: @GerardSexton Thanks, I thought about it, the only problem is that it will not scale with optional fields, the form can not be submitted with out filling in the corresponding fields.

Comment: @sarbbottam No problem. So using Javascript is what you have decided on then?

Comment: @GerardSexton may be will just drop the plan, don't want to rely on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the `::placeholder` pseudo-element, like this: http://codepen.io/thierry/pen/oxWMwy

Comment: awesome, learnt this `placeholder` trick, your solution is perfect to the example I posted. But the actual intent has been different, I have updated the post. Thanks!