# Apply style to all input text not empty via CSS

Tags: css

Can this be done via CSS3 ?

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    if (inputs[i].type == "text")
    {
        if (inputs[i].value != "")
        {
            inputs[i].style.borderBottomColor = '#448aff';
        }
    }
}

var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA");
for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++)
{
    if (textareas[i].value != "")
    {
        textareas[i].style.borderBottomColor = '#448aff';
    }
}
```

I don't mind not supporting even IE10.

Comment: As mentioned in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no), CSS can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea:valid,
input:valid {
    border-bottom-color: #448aff;
}
```

Also need to add `pattern=".*?\S.*"` (only valid with at least one non-space character) and `required` attributes to get thos pseudo-classes. You will probably also want to customise the `:invalid` state, too.

Comment: In regards to input, it's always "empty" or unrelated to that sort of :empty (empty tags, with an opening and a closing tag and no text in-between, not even whitespace => [your code works neither in Firefox nor in Chrome](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/OXEqEg?editors=1000)

Comment: @felipeals How about now? (I'm on my phone.)