# is there any CSS selector which is triggered after you type something in an input tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off" id="validform">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">


                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
                    <span class="underline"></span>
                    <label for="name">Your name</label>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">


                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
                    <span class="underline"></span>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
```

CSS:

```
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label,
textarea:valid ~ label
{
    font-size: .8em;

    top: -20px;

    color: #24cf88;
}
```

So basically label shifts on top of an input tag whenever you focus on input tag or if it is valid . it works fine with text input , but with an email input it shifts back to the bottom unless you type the correct email format. How can i keep the text shifted to the top after i type something in an email input ??
i've included the link to the website if you'd like to check how it works.

https://baziiner21.github.io

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if an input has text in it using CSS -- on a page I am visiting and do not control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no)

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `type=email` from the input and add your own validation with javascript

Comment: Rather than removing the `type=email`, I'd use JavaScript to detect if the input is filled instead to keep the semantics intact. I'd also use JavaScript validation anyway as the browsers don't all get it right.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the :valid selector. You could always use the following:

```
input:invalid ~ label {
    font-size: .8em;
    top: -20px;
    color: #cf2424;
}

/* Extra for colouring the line based on invalid input */
input:invalid + span::after, input:invalid + span::before {
    background: #cf2424;
}
```

The above code would sit alongside your existing code

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="."
```

Just add that to your email field, it will change what is considered valid to by any character entered, then your valid/invalid css styling will work.

Edit: This will require you to use novalidate on your form to prevent the browser complaining about an invalid email format.