# CSS change style if input has value or not

Tags: html, css

I have a input element with a placeholder which should appear always

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 1px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input[value=""]~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
</div>
```

And I want the pseudo placeholder to remain small if there is any text in the input field. There must be something wrong with the `input[value=""] ~ .placeholder` selector but I have no idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if an input has text in it using CSS -- on a page I am visiting and do not control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to catch this with the value attribute as it will only apply the value on page load.
Either you use the placeholder-shown as Temani Afif answered, or if you want to support edge as well, you can use a :valid selector on a required field

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 1px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input:valid~.placeholder {
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required>
  <span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks because of the edge support this should be the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) but you will need to have at least an empty placeholder

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 40px;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  font-size:16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 1px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

input:focus ~ .placeholder{
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placeholder{
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder=" ">
  <span class="placeholder">E-Mail</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ah I checked for value but there should be NO value - how about `input:not([value])` instead to avoid this placeholder attribute?

Comment: @Dr.Snail this won't work, at the CSS level you don't know if it has a value or not. You can only know if the *value* attribute is specified or not. This selector will not select input with value attribute.

Comment: Just learning about `placeholder=" "` now; what a trick I wish it was stated in the MDN docs. Thank you!