# React styled component animation not working

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create an animation for form textfield and label.
I want to be able to change the position of LabelText to top of the TextBox component.
Please let me know what I am missing on, My entered text and label are overlapping i.e. label is not animated.
Request help!

Styled components:

```
export const TextBox = styled.input`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: ${styles.backgroundGradient};
`;

export const LabelText = styled.label`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: ${styles.formContentColor};
  ${TextBox}:focus ~ &,
  ${TextBox}:not([value=""]) ~ & {
    top: -1.5em;
    left: 0;
    color: ${styles.formContentColor};
    font-size: 20px;
  }
`;

export const InputWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
`;
```

Order of placement in components

```
        <InputWrapper>
          <LabelText>Product Name</LabelText>
          <TextBox type="text" />
        </InputWrapper>
```

Comment: Please create a sandbox with your code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-water-pojf8?file=/src/StyledComponents/FormInputStyles/index.js

Comment: I think that `[value=""]` doesn't cover all. See the pen: https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/mdVqJKd ([explanation](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/moshfeu_css-tip-materialdesign-activity-6683766100368355330-0FER))

Comment: Hi Monzoor here is the link.. I am working on product details section

Answer (score 0):

I read through comment by @mosh feu and other answers on stackoverflow.

[Detect if an input has text in it using CSS -- on a page I am visiting and do not control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no)

There are couple of approaches that can serve the purpose i.e. to check whether input field is empty or not drafting them below for future refrrence.

1. input:not(:placeholder-shown):
2. input:not([value=""]):

In my case input is value of TextBox.

```
export const LabelText = styled.label`
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.6s;
  color: ${styles.formContentColor};
  ${TextBox}:focus ~ &,
  ${TextBox}:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ & {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: ${styles.formContentColor};
    font-size: 16px;
  }
`;
```