# In Material UI, how can I change the border color of the TextField only after the user enters text?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Given a `TextField`, is there a way I can detect that it has text input, and then style the border only on that condition?

I'm using the outlined `TextField`. It has placeholder text when empty.

```js
<TextField variant="outlined" />
```

Currently I've only succeeded in changing the text input color when it's filled by detecting if there's placeholder text currently visible.

In my overrides:

```js
MuiOutlinedInput: {
  root: {
    '& $notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: 'green', // default colour, want to change this when field has input
    },
  },
  input: {
    '&:not(:placeholder-shown)': {
      color: 'red', // input field text becomes red when input is provided
    },
  },
},
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfield-forked-0snbi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I want the border to also become red here when the user enters text. I can't get the placeholder trick to work on changing the border color because the border by default is on the `<fieldset>` not the `<input>`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: Updated with sandbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CSS has no pseudo selector to detect whether input is empty or not ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no)), so you must programmatically detect input and override the TextField border color

```
<TextField
  id="fullName"
  placeholder="Full name"
  variant="outlined"
  value={this.state.inputValue}
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })}
  InputProps={{
    classes: {
      notchedOutline: this.state.inputValue && classes.greenBorder
    }
  }}
/>
```

Codesandbox for demo

[image: Edit material-ui textfield (forked)]