# Input Styling on Active

Tags: css, forms, border, pseudo-element

I'm making a form for a website and want the border of the fields to change color when the field is filled with text. I was thinking I could simply do it with adding an :active state but that doesn't seem to work...

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/3uczn2bw/1/

HTML

```html
<form>
 <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
 <input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="fname" name="fname">
   <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

CSS

```css
input {
 border: none;
 outline: none!important;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 width: 300px;
}

input[type=text] {
 color: #1a1a1a;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 900;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #178926;
}
```

Comment: In this old so thread lies some info, i guess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302732/3787407 .. Just use `input:not(:placeholder-shown)` to style inputs with text.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to add some scripts. I have given the script below by using this you will achieve your goal.
In script add below code:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
        input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            this.classList.toggle('green', this.value.length > 0);
        });
    });
```

In CSS add below code:

```
.green {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

by using this CSS property you can manipulate the border properties.
This Code is useful for all input elements.