# <input> change color when it is correct

Tags: css, validation, input

I have a problem with `<input>`. I want to check whether the user has filled it out or not.

By default, the input border will be gray. When the user did not fill in the fields it will have a red border otherwise green.

I added two CSS codes:

```
input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  border-color: red;
}


input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):valid {
  border-color: green;
}
```

In `<input>` where I added required, the border is red, and here where I don't have required, the border is green. Can I change it somehow?

These are default fields that are not required.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form name="companies" method="post" class="default_ajax was-validated" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="input-field-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Place #1" id="company_name" name="company_name" class="enable_character_count form-control" required>
        <label class="company-label">Input 1</label>
    </div>

<div class="input-field-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Place #2" id="company_service_name_1" name="company_service_name_1" class="enable_character_count form-control"/>
        <label class="company-label">Input 2 </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Atleast add  image of  your output or full code snippet

Comment: i think you need to use jquery for that. not only css

Comment: Can you add your HTML code as well?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no) post. There is a working example.

Comment: @NehaSoni add code HTML.

Comment: You haven't put any placeholders into the inputs so it can never pick up your default coloring. (Do you need jquery or could you drop it?)

Comment: @AHaworth Can't you do it with CSS? If not, then I'll ask for jQuery.

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`

Comment: The CSS that you have used required a placeholder to be on those inputs that you want to have the default coloring.

Comment: @AHaworth Can you give me a hint? Drop some code?

Comment: To get the default colouring start by putting a placeholder attribute in the inputs. It could be just a space to see what happens.

Comment: @AHaworth is-valid in form-control?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand your comment. Have you tried putting in a placeholder attribute.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, doesn't work.

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools to see exactly who/where is setting the CSS?