# The CSS input effect ceases to work when the 'required' attribute is taken out

Tags: html, css

Recently, I've been trying to make a nice form but I came across some problems.

Basically when I remove the "required attribute" from the input everything stops working as it should.
I found a fake solution i's just remove tilde ~ sign from valid like below:

```
.input-data input:valid ~ label {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  fontsize: 14px; color: #2e4f5c;
}
```

But after this when I leave from the input the label comes back to the original position and doesn't keep like when I have focus and when the label goes down it covers the text that I entered.

This is a DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/henriqpohl/wg5L94pk/5/

Does anyone have any idea how the input can work exactly the same as the input with the required attribute?

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`), the selector then matches `label` that is a child of `input`. This matches nothing, so you could have deleted the entire selector.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302732/21849374) is answered in the question that is linked to in the comments of your question.

You'll need to use the [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) pseudo-class along with the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class to indicate when text has been entered into the input (and therefore the placeholder is no longer shown.)

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label
```

You'll also need to use the [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#placeholder) attribute for the `input` element but the placeholder can be blank.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="">
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
  max-width: 950px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 950px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.container .text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.container form {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.container form .form-row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0;
}
form .form-row .input-data {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

form .form-row .input-data-check {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.input-data input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.input-data input:focus ~ label,
.input-data input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #2e4f5c;
}

.input-data label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.input-data .underline {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-data .underline:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2e4f5c;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.input-data input:focus ~ .underline:before,
.input-data input:valid ~ .underline:before {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">MY FORM</div>

  <form action="#">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" required>
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label for="">Nome</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-data">
        <input type="text" placeholder="">
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label for="">Empresa</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding empty placeholder in the html worked for me.