# Input not(:empty) not working properly

Tags: html, css

I just want to add background color when input has a value. So I tried this way.

First add default background color when empty.

```
input:empty {
  background-color:white ;
}
```

Then I tried to detect not empty with

```
input:not(:empty) {
 background-color:green ;
}
```

Why this isn't working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639282/notempty-css-selector-is-not-working/35408000

Comment: not is for simple selectors only - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors