# Onchange event that does not wait for input box to lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `onchange` event for a HTML input box does not fire until the textbox loses focus. Is there a way to make it fire as soon as the contents change?

Here's an example of `onchange` firing after focus loss: http://jsfiddle.net/McjqW/

Comment: You haven't provided much context so hard to know if this applies, but be aware that there are often significant accessibility issues associated with what you are proposing (e: screenreader users need to be able to explore the options in a select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeypress) or [`onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeydown) event. Note that this event is not standard, and different browsers may expose this functionality under different names. The DOM level 3 standard defines a [`keypress`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order) event which would be "the" answer, but again I can't vouch for browser support.

**Update:** `onkeypress` [reportedly enjoys wide support](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwfxum.php).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Any idea which browsers support it and which don't?

Comment: or even the onkeyup event if you want to fire the code after the press has been completed.

Comment: `keypress` is implemented in all major browsers. However, it's possible to change the input's value without using the keyboard: paste and drag-and-drop, for example. The HTML5 `input` event solves this.

Comment: @TimDown: Thank you for the heads up and +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeyup) instead

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(this.id)">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/McjqW/1/

Comment: Can someone please explain me why [my edit to this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/McjqW/14/) does not work?

Comment: @vault It's because the javascript load type (click the settings button in the corner of the JS window) needs to be set to "in head" for your code to work - https://jsfiddle.net/McjqW/15/

Comment: thanks. it also works "in body", that's what I desired.

Answer (score 1):

You need the HTML5 `input` event. It's not quite fully cross-browser but there's a workaround for IE < 9, which is the only major browser that doesn't have it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524996/96100) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536115/96100).