# Limiting characters in textbox on type and paste with javascript .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, copy-paste, typing

Here is the scenario:

I am trying to show indication "XY characters left" and also limit characters in texbox as user types. I have multiline teboxes too, so MaxLength doesn't always work for me (don't worry, I check on server side too).

Here is what I have learned: onkeyup works perfectly with this function:

```
function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) {
chars = txtMsg.value.length;
document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
if (chars > CharLength) {
    txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
}
}
```

But, I also need to detect pasted values. If user uses CTRL+V it's OK, but this doesn't work if user pastes using mouse.
I have learned, that in this case we need delay (here):
[Javascript OnPaste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972954/javascript-onpaste)

So, I updated (added onPaste event) like this:

```
/* FUNCTION THAT LIMITS INSERTED CHARACTERS IN TEXTBOX */

function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) {
chars = txtMsg.value.length;
document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
if (chars > CharLength) {
    txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
}
}

/* Delay is needed if user uses paste with mouse (right click and paste). After delay same function (LimtCharacters) can be called*/
function pasted(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) {
setTimeout(function () {
    LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator);
}, 10);
}
```

Markup in ASPX file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="255" 
                onKeyup="LimtCharacters(this,255,'lblTitleCount')"
                onPaste="pasted(this,255,'lblTitleCount')" />

<asp:Label ID="lblTitleCount" Text="255" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

lblTitle is the label that displays "characters left" value.

It works perfect in FireFox and Chrome. But it doesn't work in IE.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using visual studio 2010 .net.

Any hint/help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: You could use the `input` event instead of both `paste` and `keyup`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7536115/96100, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbTitle").on("input", function () {
            LimtCharacters(this, 255, 'lblTitleCount');
        });
    });               
</script>


//FUNCTION THAT LIMITS INSERTED CHARACTERS IN TEXTBOX 

function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator){
    chars = txtMsg.value.length;
    document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
    if (chars > CharLength) {
        txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
        //Text in textbox was trimmed, re-set indicator value to 0
        document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works also in IE. Marked as answer. Thanks!

Comment: And don't forget to set ClientIDMode="Static" on TextBox in order this to work!