# Responsive Rich Editor Preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Consider this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tuUym/)**.

The essential bit is the JavaScript:

```
function encodeInput(editor) {
    theText = editor.val();
    theText = theText.replace(/\*\*\*(.*?)\*\*\*/, '<strong><i>$1</i></strong>', 'g');
    theText = theText.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/, '<strong>$1</strong>', 'g');
    theText = theText.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/, '<i>$1</i>', 'g');
    console.log(theText);
    $('#preview').html(theText);
}

$(function() {
    $editor = $('#editor');
    $editor.keyup(function() {
        encodeInput($(this));
    });
});
```

Tested and works great (I do need the `\*\*\*` part or it doesn't work).
Anyways, on to the main course

### The Problem

Because I'm using `keyup`, the script is not very responsive (eg. it only "runs" once the user had let go of the key). I want it to behave more like the editor here on StackOverflow, where the key is pressed and response occurs immidiately.

I tried using `keydown` and `keypress` but it seems as if the `val()` attribute is not updated when it runs, so I can't really know the updated value.

### In Short

How can I make it more responsive, so that when the user pressed a key, the preview is automatically updated??

Comment: Two suggestions: Use `<em>` instead of `<i>` and if you want to add proper markdown support, consider porting markdown-python to JavaScript instead of using regexes. Its approach with plugins, a parse tree, etc is really nice and much cleaner IMO.

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain the -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `input` event in most browsers and the `propertychange` event in IE < 9. These events fire immediately after the textarea's value is updated.

Here's an updated demo using these events:

http://jsfiddle.net/muWm2/1/

I've written about this in a few places on SO. Here are two of them:

- [Catch only keypresses that change input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488171/catch-only-keypresses-that-change-input/6490241#6490241)
- [jQuery keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519936/jquery-keyboard-events/5524996#5524996)

I would recommend against updating the preview on every single change to the textarea's value because it could quickly get unresponsive, which is a big no-no for user experience. I'd suggest "debouncing" the event, in this case waiting for a period of user inactivity (say half a second) before updating the preview. Here's an answer and a link that may help:

- [How to trigger an onkeyup event that's delayed until a user pauses their typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/javascript-jquery-make-an-ajax-request-when-a-user-is-typing-in-a-textarea/1621309#1621309)
- [Debouncing Javascript Methods by John Hann](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/)

Comment: flawless answer. bounty in 16 hours :P

Answer (score 0):

You can [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) both the `keyup` and `keydown` events:

```
$editor.bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    encodeInput($(this));
});
```

I noticed that only the first occurrence was working, adding the `g` flag to the regex seemed to help, and for the purpose of the jsfiddle demo only, unchecking "normalize css" made the bold text appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuUym/3/

Comment: Still the same problem. Does not work until the key is released.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, whereas it did not before. Unfortunately I can't test any other browser at the moment, my laptop crashed and I'm on the gf's computer. BTW might want to add `word-wrap:break-word;` to the preview pane.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well, and it doesn't work as intended for me.

Comment: I'd be surprised if we're not seeing the same thing, maybe testing it differently or I misunderstood the question. What exactly isn't working? How can I reproduce it? I'm not seeing "Does not work until the key is released", it works on my end (for example, if I hold `s` I see `sssssssss` in both panes, and it updates as I type including the formatting). I'm off to bed, best of luck.

Comment: Hmm, I do notice a little lag now (especially on the first character, not very noticeable when actually typing) - but this still seems to be an improvement. Hope you get a better answer.

Comment: Try holding the key down for about a second, you'll see the larger lag I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Keypress fires when the key is pressed continously, so you have to bind it to keypress in order to see the result. And thats it.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuUym/4/

UPDATE: I see what you mean. Maybe you need an input poller? Check out the de obfuscated wmd code. That will help you achieve the lagless editor you aim for:

[WMD Download](https://github.com/derobins/wmd/downloads)

Comment: Try pressing backspace, it does not seem to update deleted characters.

Comment: Read the question and test your own code, binding keypress causes the `val()` not to be updated (meaning I write L-o-r-e-m and see L-o-r-e). I only see the last character if I press on another key (like shift or ctrl).