# Autolink URL in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, range, selection

When the user finishes to type in a URL in a contenteditable div, I want to autolink it, like Medium does: [image: http://d.pr/i/DsZH+]).

I'm wondering how it is possible to achieve that using selection/range (I do not need to support IE, only modern versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari), if possible without rangy (but if that is the only solution I would use it).

I'm able to detect if an URL preceed the caret after a user presses the space key, but I can't have `execcommand('createLink'...)` work on my range.

Here is a very simplified example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Florent2/Qa4EF/1/)) where I try to format in bold the 4 characters preceding the caret after the user presses the space key:

```
$("#editor").on("keypress", function(event) {
  var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if(/\s/.test(pressedChar)) {
    var selection   = window.getSelection();
    var range       = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 4);

    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('bold', false);
  }
}
```

When I type a few characters and then a space, the 4 previous characters are not formatted in bold as I'd like, they just disappear from the div and only the new characters that I type afterwards are bolded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636218/jquery-convert-text-url-to-link-as-typing/14637351#14637351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a workaround, without using `execCommand`:

1. delete the range content: `range.deleteContents()`
2. create the link node I want to insert
3. insert the node in the range: `range.insertNode(createdLinkNode)`
4. place the caret right after the inserted node:

```
range.setStartAfter(createdLinkNode);
range.setEndAfter(createdLinkNode);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```