# How to auto convert an url into a hyperlink when it is pasted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

When I tried to paste an url in the text box like `https://stackoverflow.com/` it doesn't convert to a hyperlink automatically.

i tried using regular expression this is the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759302/how-to-detect-links-with-out-anchor-element-in-a-plain-text) i asked before. The function that i use in this question works fine, but actually it will replace all links including links in tags (IMG, existing A HREFs).

**i dont want to use regx** if i use regx convertion happens when i click any submit or save button.

**When a user paste's a url in a text box it should automatically convert any link to hyperlink****

i've tried this using regx

For example:

```
what = "<span>In the task system, is there a way to automatically have any site / page URL or image URL be hyperlinked in a new window?</span><br><br><span>So If I type or copy http://www.stackoverflow.com/&nbsp; for example anywhere in the description, in any of the internal messages or messages to clients, it automatically is a hyperlink in a new window.</span><br><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">http://www.stackoverflow.com/</a><br>    <br><span>Or if I input an image URL anywhere in support description, internal messages or messages to cleints, it automatically is a hyperlink in a new window:</span><br> <span>https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg</span><br><br><a href="https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg">https://static.doubleclick.net/viewad/4327673/1-728x90.jpg</a><br><br><br><span>This would save us a lot time in task building, reviewing and creating messages.</span>



Test URL's
        http://www.stackoverflow.com/
        https://stackoverflow.com/
        https://stackoverflow.com/
        www.stackoverflow.com
        //stackoverflow.com/
        <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>https://stackoverflow.com/</a>";
```

I've tried this code

```
function Linkify(what) {
    str = what; out = ""; url = ""; i = 0;
    do {
        url = str.match(/((https?:\/\/)?([a-z\-]+\.)*[\-\w]+(\.[a-z]{2,4})+(\/[\w\_\-\?\=\&\.]*)*(?![a-z]))/i);
        if(url!=null) {
            // get href value
            href = url[0];
            if(href.substr(0,7)!="http://") href = "http://"+href;

            // where the match occured
            where = str.indexOf(url[0]);

            // add it to the output
            out += str.substr(0,where);

            // link it
            out += '<a href="'+href+'" target="_blank">'+url[0]+'</a>';

            // prepare str for next round
            str = str.substr((where+url[0].length));
        } else {
            out += str;
            str = "";
        }
    } while(str.length>0);
    return out;
}
```

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgNtR/3/) that's not working***

**Is it possible to convert it automatically when we paste a url in a text box like we are getting in stack over flow can I have some examples?**

Thanks.

Comment: You should post, what you have tried first..! {CODE}

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i tried using regular expression in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759302/how-to-detect-links-with-out-anchor-element-in-a-plain-text  i mentioned that in the question above

Comment: @ZiNNED paste an url in the text box

Comment: @dhee Show the code that you have used while making an attempt. so that we could inherit that code and expel a possible solution for you.. Are you getting what i am trying to say...?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the link i gave is my question i asked before that's why i have not given any sample now i updated the question please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Autolink URL in ContentEditable Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301080/autolink-url-in-contenteditable-iframe)

In this question i answered

so that when a user paste's a url in a richtextbox it automatically converts any link to hyperlink - here my richtextbox is not a div its an iframe

if your's is a div or any other you can get answer from these two questions

[Autolink URL in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127418/autolink-url-in-contenteditable) [jQuery: Convert text URL to link as typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636218/jquery-convert-text-url-to-link-as-typing/14637351#14637351)

here's the code

```
autoAppLink: function (Iframe) {
    var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        saveSelection = function (containerEl) {
            var range = iframe[0].contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
            preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
            preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

            return {
                start: start,
                end: start + range.toString().length
            }
        };

        restoreSelection = function (containerEl, savedSel) {
            var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            range.collapse(true);
            var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

            while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
                if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                    var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                    if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                        range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                        foundStart = true;
                    }
                    if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                        range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                        stop = true;
                    }
                    charIndex = nextCharIndex;
                } else {
                    var i = node.childNodes.length;
                    while (i--) {
                        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            var sel = iframe[0].contentWindow.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        saveSelection = function (containerEl) {
            var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
            var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
            preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
            var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

            return {
                start: start,
                end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
            }
        };

        restoreSelection = function (containerEl, savedSel) {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
            textRange.collapse(true);
            textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
            textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
            textRange.select();
        };
    }

    function createLink(matchedTextNode) {
        var el = document.createElement("a");
        el.href = matchedTextNode.data;
        el.target = "_blank";
        el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
        return el;
    }

    function shouldLinkifyContents(el) {
        return el.tagName != "A";
    }

    function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc, shouldSurroundFunc) {
        var child = el.lastChild;
        while (child) {
            if (child.nodeType == 1 && shouldSurroundFunc(el)) {
                surroundInElement(child, regex, createLink, shouldSurroundFunc);
            } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
            }
            child = child.previousSibling;
        }
    }

    function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
        var parent = textNode.parentNode;
        var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
        while (textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data))) {
            matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
            matchedText = result[0];
            matchLength = matchedText.length;
            textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
                matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
            surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
            parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
            parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
        }
    }

    var iframe = Iframe,
        textbox = iframe.contents().find("body")[0];
    var urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^ ]+)/;

    function updateLinks() {
        var savedSelection = saveSelection(textbox);
        surroundInElement(textbox, urlRegex, createLink, shouldLinkifyContents);
        restoreSelection(textbox, savedSelection);
    }

    var $textbox = $(textbox);


    $textbox.focus();

    var keyTimer = null, keyDelay = 1000;

    $textbox.keyup(function () {
        if (keyTimer) {
            window.clearTimeout(keyTimer);
        }
        keyTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {

            updateLinks();
            keyTimer = null;
        }, keyDelay);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/(<a href=")?((https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)))(">(.*)<\/a>)?/gi, function () {
    return '<a href="' + arguments[2] + '">' + (arguments[7] || arguments[2]) + '</a>'
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle here</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LgNtR/7/) and [<kbd>Regexr</kbd>](http://regexr.com/3910k)

Comment: Vinz243 really thanks if this works i am really thankful to you

Comment: Vinz243 see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgNtR/6/) this dosent work with regexp i want to convert it automatically when i paste a url

Comment: Open you broser console and you will realize that you forgot to include jQuery...

Comment: this is not working try `http://foo.co.uk/
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar

<a href="http://foo.co.uk/">no</a>
<a href="http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar">yes</a>` with your regx

Comment: that's not finding even a single url if i place `http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar` in fiddle and run thats not linking

Comment: Yes it does for me. Please link it

Comment: `$('div').html(newStr)` means it must be placed in a div. In a real life app it should even have an id.

Comment: ahh im sorry but this works in fiddle in my code that fails :(

Answer (score 4):

For anyone finding this question in 2021 and looking to have a nice function to do it all, here's one I found on this [blog post](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/97/how-to-convert-url-websites-email-from-a-string-to-html-a-tags-with-javascript):

```
function linkify(inputText) {
    var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;

    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

    return replacedText;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer (improved Version including video links).

See also this [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/philipeachille/pen/yLBGYrW).

```js
const convertLinks = ( input ) => {

  let text = input;
  const linksFound = text.match( /(?:www|https?)[^\s]+/g );
  const aLink = [];

  if ( linksFound != null ) {

    for ( let i=0; i<linksFound.length; i++ ) {
      let replace = linksFound[i];
      if ( !( linksFound[i].match( /(http(s?)):\/\// ) ) ) { replace = 'http://' + linksFound[i] }
      let linkText = replace.split( '/' )[2];
      if ( linkText.substring( 0, 3 ) == 'www' ) { linkText = linkText.replace( 'www.', '' ) }
      if ( linkText.match( /youtu/ ) ) {

        let youtubeID = replace.split( '/' ).slice(-1)[0];
        aLink.push( '<div class="video-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeID + '" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>' )
      }
      else if ( linkText.match( /vimeo/ ) ) {
        let vimeoID = replace.split( '/' ).slice(-1)[0];
        aLink.push( '<div class="video-wrapper"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + vimeoID + '" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>' )
      }
      else {
        aLink.push( '<a href="' + replace + '" target="_blank">' + linkText + '</a>' );
      }
      text = text.split( linksFound[i] ).map(item => { return aLink[i].includes('iframe') ? item.trim() : item } ).join( aLink[i] );
    }
    return text;

  }
  else {
    return input;
  }
}
```

this replaces long and clumsy links within plain texts to short clickable links within that text. (And also wraps videos in responsive iframes)

Example:

```html
This clumsy link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634850/javascript-convert-plain-text-links-to-clickable-links/52544985#52544985 is very clumsy and this http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split is not much better. This one www.apple.com is nice but www could be omitted
```

Becomes:

```html
This clumsy link <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634850/javascript-convert-plain-text-links-to-clickable-links/52544985#52544985" target="_blank">stackoverflow.com</a> is very clumsy and this <a href="http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split" target="_blank">developer.mozilla.org</a> is not much better. This one <a href="http://www.apple.com" target="_blank">apple.com</a> is nice but www could be omitted
```

Is displayed as:

This clumsy link [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634850/javascript-convert-plain-text-links-to-clickable-links/52544985#52544985) is very clumsy and this [developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is not much better. This one [apple.com](http://www.apple.com) is nice but www can be removed

Answer (score 0):

for js folks, you can use a library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autolinker

```
var autolinker = new Autolinker( {
    newWindow : false,
    truncate  : 30
} );

var html = autolinker.link( "Joe went to www.yahoo.com" );
// produces: 'Joe went to <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo.com</a>'
```