# Autolink URL in ContentEditable Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection, contenteditable

I have a content editable Iframe  I want to autolink it, like : [image]
My content editable Iframe  look like [image]

i tried using regular expression in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759302/how-to-detect-links-with-out-anchor-element-in-a-plain-text) i asked before. The function that i use in this question works fine, but actually it will replace all links including links in tags (IMG, existing A HREFs).

**But i dont want to use regx** if i use regx convertion happens when i click any submit or save button.

**When a user paste's a url in a content editable Iframe it should automatically convert any link to hyperlink**

i tried with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJfx7/2/) too but :( can't get this

Html

`<div class="workzone" style="height: 150px;"><iframe id="idContent" width="600" height="280"></iframe></div>`

I have tried this resource but could'nt find how to fix this for a content editable Iframe. Perhaps this for contenteditable div

[Autolink URL in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127418/autolink-url-in-contenteditable) 
[jQuery: Convert text URL to link as typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636218/jquery-convert-text-url-to-link-as-typing/14637351#14637351)

can anyone please help me with content editable Iframe autolinking Thanks.

Comment: So what's wrong with the answers you've found? Is it just that they need to be adapted to working in an iframe?

Comment: @TimDown yes i want that to work in an content editable iframe

Comment: i am getting error `IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount at var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);`

Comment: @TimDown can you please help me to fix this in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJfx7/2/)

Comment: I may try and have a look later but I can't guarantee anything. It should only be a matter of replacing references to `window` and `document` to variables extracted from the iframe's Window and Document (`contentWindow` and `contentDocument` properties of the iframe element will help).

Comment: hay tim thank you this is working now

Comment: @TimDown  need help in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8hYSc/3/ in the contenteditable box when we just paste http:// and leave it that's also getting hyperlinked can you please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally its working and thanks to @Tim Down for his code and replies

This is what i did - Autolink in an content editable Iframe

```
autoAppLink: function (Iframe) {
        var saveSelection, restoreSelection;

        if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
            saveSelection = function (containerEl) {
                var range = iframe[0].contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
                preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
                preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
                var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

                return {
                    start: start,
                    end: start + range.toString().length
                }
            };

            restoreSelection = function (containerEl, savedSel) {
                var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
                range.collapse(true);
                var nodeStack = [containerEl], node, foundStart = false, stop = false;

                while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
                    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                        var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
                        if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                            range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                            foundStart = true;
                        }
                        if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                            range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                            stop = true;
                        }
                        charIndex = nextCharIndex;
                    } else {
                        var i = node.childNodes.length;
                        while (i--) {
                            nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                var sel = iframe[0].contentWindow.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (document.selection) {
            saveSelection = function (containerEl) {
                var selectedTextRange = document.selection.createRange();
                var preSelectionTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                preSelectionTextRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
                preSelectionTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", selectedTextRange);
                var start = preSelectionTextRange.text.length;

                return {
                    start: start,
                    end: start + selectedTextRange.text.length
                }
            };

            restoreSelection = function (containerEl, savedSel) {
                var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                textRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
                textRange.collapse(true);
                textRange.moveEnd("character", savedSel.end);
                textRange.moveStart("character", savedSel.start);
                textRange.select();
            };
        }

        function createLink(matchedTextNode) {
            var el = document.createElement("a");
            el.href = matchedTextNode.data;
            el.target = "_blank";
            el.appendChild(matchedTextNode);
            return el;
        }

        function shouldLinkifyContents(el) {
            return el.tagName != "A";
        }

        function surroundInElement(el, regex, surrounderCreateFunc, shouldSurroundFunc) {
            var child = el.lastChild;
            while (child) {
                if (child.nodeType == 1 && shouldSurroundFunc(el)) {
                    surroundInElement(child, regex, createLink, shouldSurroundFunc);
                } else if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                    surroundMatchingText(child, regex, surrounderCreateFunc);
                }
                child = child.previousSibling;
            }
        }

        function surroundMatchingText(textNode, regex, surrounderCreateFunc) {
            var parent = textNode.parentNode;
            var result, surroundingNode, matchedTextNode, matchLength, matchedText;
            while (textNode && (result = regex.exec(textNode.data))) {
                matchedTextNode = textNode.splitText(result.index);
                matchedText = result[0];
                matchLength = matchedText.length;
                textNode = (matchedTextNode.length > matchLength) ?
                    matchedTextNode.splitText(matchLength) : null;
                surroundingNode = surrounderCreateFunc(matchedTextNode.cloneNode(true));
                parent.insertBefore(surroundingNode, matchedTextNode);
                parent.removeChild(matchedTextNode);
            }
        }

        var iframe = Iframe,
            textbox = iframe.contents().find("body")[0];
        var urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^ ]+)/;

        function updateLinks() {
            var savedSelection = saveSelection(textbox);
            surroundInElement(textbox, urlRegex, createLink, shouldLinkifyContents);
            restoreSelection(textbox, savedSelection);
        }

        var $textbox = $(textbox);


        $textbox.focus();

        var keyTimer = null, keyDelay = 1000;

        $textbox.keyup(function () {
            if (keyTimer) {
                window.clearTimeout(keyTimer);
            }
            keyTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {

                updateLinks();
                keyTimer = null;
            }, keyDelay);
        });

    }
```