# How can i detect any type of url with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, contenteditable

Is there any regx to detect complete url

In my code i am using this regx **urlRegex** to find out any url in my content editable iframe's text

```
urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^ ]+)/
```

iam getting issue when i type **http://** this gets detecting and this is not detecting www.google.com

i have to detect url's like

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
www.google.com
http://localhost:51932/default.aspx
```

my code is

```
var iframe = Iframe,
    textbox = iframe.contents().find("body")[0],
    urlRegex = /http(s?):\/\/($|[^ ]+)/;
```

In this question [Autolink URL in ContentEditable Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301080/autolink-url-in-contenteditable-iframe) i am trying to fix regx

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: did you read my question? @AvinashRaj

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/kX8hK8/1

Comment: when i type http:// in the text box that http:// is also getting detected due to the regx i am using is there any regx that detect a complete url

Comment: @hjpotter92 i need regx for javascript can you please help

Comment: Id change your regex firstly to test if http or not. Like so `/(http(s?):\/\/?).../` im on my phone so if anything is messed up im sorry but others will get my drift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1):

Updated version - tested

```
^((https?|s?ftp):\/\/)?(((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))|((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])))(:[1-9][0-9]+)?(\/)?([/?].+)?$
```

Only two fails (for now :))

```
http://localhost:51932/default.aspx
https://192.168.0.25:5132/default.aspx
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
mailto:somebody@google.com                         // fail
somebody@google.com                                // fail 
www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring
http://www.xxx.events
sftp://ftp.something.com
www.google.co.in
www.xxx.com
```

Comment: check this fiddle this dosent work for my case http://regex101.com/r/nT7gA2/2

Comment: hay @hex494D49 can you please help me to get www.xxx.com or like www.google.co.in

Comment: @dhee Try the updated version