# Capture Copy/Paste/Select in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i capture the following keys in `Textbox` using `JavaScript`?

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

<kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

### Following is the original Situation.

I have three `Textboxes` for Phones numbers. `Textbox1` max length is 3 , 2nd's is 3 and 3rd is 4. When user types three digits in `TextBox1` the cursor moves automatically to `TextBox2` same thing happens with TextBox2 as well as TextBox3. I am handling this functionality in keyup event. Now, I am parallely using your code. But it moves in keyup event as well. This case happens when all TextBoxes are filled. Now suppose I am in TextBox1 and presses Ctl + A . This moves the user to third TextBox(unacceptable case). This is the issue.

Comment: jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1503425/284240 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/238835/284240 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904944/284240

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript

Comment: @Tim thanks for the reply. Actually, I need it in Javascript.

Comment: @PankajGarg: jQuery **is** nothing else than javascript.

Comment: @chuck it's answer is in JQuery.

Comment: @Tim, actually i have already checked this answer.

Comment: @PankajGarg there are answers attached to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript which work and do not require jQuery

Comment: @PankajGarg: Actually you don't even need to download and add jQuery to your project, you can use it from `googleapis`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `select`, [`copy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.oncopy) and [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste) events respectively. Pretty much universally supported these days.

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("textBoxId");
textBox.onpaste = function() {
    alert("paste");
};
```

Likewise for the other events. Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/EC2Hf/

Comment: can you please tell about ctl + A also? Thanks

Comment: @Pankaj: That's covered by the `select` event. I added a demo to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed link/Demo. +1

Comment: This seems to make it fire twice

Comment: @pbfy0 Can you explain it bit more please?

Comment: @Tim Down - can i set the focus also using e in the same event handler?

Comment: @PankajGarg: If you're getting any of these events then the text box must already have the focus.

Comment: @Tim, I want to pass "`this`" in the parameter list. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @Tim Down - Your post is failing in one scenario when you double click the text in textbox and control goes to the event handler. This should not be the case as i need to detect just ctl + A/C/V

Comment: @PankajGarg: Why do you just want the keyboard events?

Comment: @Tim - Let me explain you the complete situation first. I have three `Textboxes` for Phones numbers. `Textbox1`  max length is 3 , 2nd's is 3 and 3rd is 4. When user types three digits in `textBox1` the cursor moves automatically to `TextBox2` same thing happens with `TextBox2` as well as `TextBox3`. I am handling this functionality in keyup event. Now, I am parallely using your code. But it moves in keyup event as well. This case happens when all TextBoxes are filled. Now suppose I am in TextBox1 and presses Ctl + A . This moves the user to third TextBox(unacceptable case). This is the issue.

Comment: @PankajGarg: Ah. I'd suggest using the `input` event instead then. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5524996/96100

Comment: @PankajGarg i get 2 dialog boxes when I copy or paste

Answer (score 1):

And what about right click, osx that does not use control, the edit copy option on the browser, the button on my old keyboard, etc?

There is more than just key presses.

That said, most browsers support

[oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.oncopy) and [onpaste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onpaste) events.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to first check if the ctrl button was clicked and then the correspnding letter keys. This [link](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-ctrl-n-and-other-ctrl-key-combinations-in-javascript.html) may help you out