# Shot event when the value in an input is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```

I need that, when the value of the `input.#foo` is changed, **without blur**, it shot my event. Here comes the problem: I can't use `onkey` events because the input is dinamically received by a virtual HTML-composed keyboard.

I can easily do, with the true keyboard:

```
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  // Implementation
});
```

The W3C recommend using `onchange`, but `onchange` **only** works after the `blur` event occurs. I need a mix of `onkeypress`, to be dynamic, on  time modify, and `onchange`, to know when it changes. You can see this: http://jsfiddle.net/zuq733La/

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I can't use keyup. I just don't have a keyboard to shot keyup event. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zuq733La/2/ use `textInput`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery keyboard events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519936/jquery-keyboard-events)

Comment: The question above might have a _misleading_ title considering what you're trying to achieve, but the answer would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zuq733La/2/)

use `textInput` it will check for every character added

```
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener('textInput', function () {
   alert('Value changed!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way I can think of (without using `blur`, `change`, `keypress`, `keyup` or `keydown` events) is using a `setInterval()`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zuq733La/4/)**

```
var value=$('#foo').val();
setInterval(function(){
    if(value!=$('#foo').val()){
        value=$('#foo').val();
        //here you need to write what will happen if the value is changed
    }
},50);
```

in the DEMO you can see that even if you copy and paste a text (using only your mouse even without blurring the input) the event fires.